# How are URLSesssion priority and networkServiceType really used

Tags: ios, urlsession

URLRequest has the [networkServiceType](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlrequest/networkservicetype) field with the following description.

> The network service type provides a hint to the operating system about what the underlying traffic is used for. This hint enhances the system's ability to prioritize traffic, determine how quickly it needs to wake up the cellular or Wi-Fi radio, and so on. It improves the system’s ability to optimally balance battery life, performance, and other considerations.

> For example, specify the NSURLRequest.NetworkServiceType.background service type if your app is performing a download that wasn’t requested by the user—like prefetching content so that it’s available when the user chooses to view it. By contrast, continually connected voice and video apps should use the NSURLRequest.NetworkServiceType.voice, NSURLRequest.NetworkServiceType.voip, or video service types, as appropriate.

Then URLSessionTask has the [priority](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiontask/url_session_task_priority) field with the following description

> To provide hints to a host on how to prioritize URL session tasks from your app, specify a priority for each task. Specifying a priority provides only a hint and does not guarantee performance. If you don’t specify a priority, a URL session task has a priority of defaultPriority, with a value of 0.5.

> There are three named priorities you can employ, described in URL Session Task Priority.

> You can specify or change a task’s priority at any time, but not all networking protocols respond to changes after a task has started. There is no API to let you determine the effective priority for a task from a host’s perspective.

My initial assumption was that the system maps networkServiceType values into priorities when creating a task from a request, but this doesn't seem to be the case. I tried every value of networkServiceType and the `URLSessionTask.priority` was always `default`.

What effect do these fields actually have? How do these work together? What should I be using to prioritize traffic?

Answer (score 0):

They are two different things.
The first one is a configuration setting that will affect QoS and low level networking settings.

The second one is simply to prioritize one request over the other. They are complimentary.